# CNC a hemisphere in SolidWorks

Tags: solidworks, machining, cnc

[image]

Dear all, I am currently learning CNC Milling software. I have successfully be able to simulate the toolpath for milling a square block to a hemisphere. May I ask how to add another operation, that is to mill to clean the surface of the hemisphere by which the toolpath drill must be always perpendicular to the hemisphere surface. You can download my working simulation uploaded solidcam file at google drive [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mhzHVst1O7Sv_ZwLfPC5o187T0xXVuzO/view?usp=sharing). I will really appreciate any help I can get :). Thank you for reading and have a nice day !!

Comment: Hello Maximus Su and Engineering; this question was asked over at [Robotics.SE] but I think it's a much better fit for the community here so I migrated it. I also edited the tags to appropriate ones that exist on this site. Good luck, OP, I hope you get an answer!